# Sentence correction : ....was in considerable measure the life of the nation as well

Tags: exam-questions

> The later part of Gandhi's life(a) / till he was assassinated (b) was in considerable measure the life of the nation as well.(c)

This is an error spotting question asked in my exam. Although I can judge that the error is in part C but I can't figure out what it is and how to correct it. Dont't know if it is error in printing or what but by reading the part C I can't make  head or tail what the speaker is actually trying to say. Can anyone tell what's the error and how to correct it or is the whole sentence sense less?

Comment: (a) should be "The later part of Gandhi's life". In (c) I would use "*by* considerable measure" but I can't say whether *in* is wrong.

Comment: @user3169 Sorry by mistake I typed 'the' with 'Gandhi's life' . It's without 'the' , I have updated the question.

Comment: There is no error in the sentence. The author of the question may imagine that _later_ is an error, and that _latter_ is "correct", but either word can be appropriate. The author may also imagine that _till_ is an error, but it is not. When an exam is written by a non-native speaker, there is simply no way to guess what that author may imagine is an  "error."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see no error here, as others have said.

Stripping out the details, I think the sentence is saying:

> Gandhi's life was the life of the nation.

This is a metaphor of sorts. The author is saying that Gandhi's life story is intertwined with the nation's history, and that you can't study the former without learning about the latter at the same time.

It's a descriptive way of saying that the later part of Gandhi's life was engaged primarily in events that were part of the public record and became part of the way the nation is understood today. But their way of saying it is more succinct and elegant.